# Compare to Items in Array?

Tags: arrays, swift

Looking to compare a few int's and an array in a for-in loop:

```
for i in 0...47 where i != someNumber && i != someOtherNumber && i != myArrayOfAFewNumbers[] {
doSomething()
}
```

I can't seem to find a simple solution.  Thanks!

Comment: `where !([someNumber, someOtherNumber] + myArrayOfAFewNumbers).contains(i)`

Comment: That worked; thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of excluded items first, e.g.:

```
let excludedItems = [someNumber, someOtherNumber] + myArrayOfAFewNumbers

for i in 0...47 where !excludedItems.contains(i) {
  doSomething()
}
```

you can also use a `Set` to reach better complexity:

```
let excludedItems = Set([someNumber, someOtherNumber] + myArrayOfAFewNumbers)
```